# How to get the fluid autocomplete widget to work in TYPO3 v10

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I am trying to get the Fluid search widget **autocomplete** to work in my custom extension in TYPO3 v10.
The problem is that I am getting the following error message when typing anything in my search field:

http://www.local-website.com/?id=2&type=7076&action=autocomplete&term=teststring - 500 (Internal Server Error).. After examining the exact response of that page request, here's the specific error:

*"No widget context was found for the Ajax Widget Identifier "". This only happens if AJAX URIs are called without including the widget on a page"*

Here's my Fluid autocomplete widget code as I have implemented in my extension's Fluid template:

```
<f:widget.autocomplete for="search-items" objects="{allItems}" searchProperty="title" storeSession="false"/>
```

I have not set up anything specific for AJAX (i.e. I have not set up page type **707** as I would not know how to do this)...

Here's the widget information page I'm using:
https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/10.4/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Widget/Autocomplete.html

Comment: I do not have an answer to your problem but just want to point out, that Fluid Widgets are deprecated and removed in TYPO3 11 - see https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Breaking-92529-AllFluidWidgetFunctionalityRemoved.html

If you want a future proof solution, you should consider to create the required functionality on your own in a custom extension (e.g. PSR-15 middleware or Extbase action).

Comment: Good point @derhansen, thanks for your valuable input!

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the new parameter `storeSession="false"` is used.
In TYPO3 v9 this parameter didn't exist.
Using the widget like this should work like intended:

```
<f:widget.autocomplete for="search-items" objects="{allItems}" searchProperty="title"/>
```

Usually the parameteres look like this:

```
?id=1&type=7076&fluid-widget-id=9c31f0bb1b5f5f953e84f6b57af102b4&action=autocomplete&term=Ma
```

When the parameter `storeSession=false` is used it looks like this:

```
?id=1&type=7076&action=autocomplete&term=Ma
```

That means that the widget doesn't transfer the correct link to the AJAX script.

The issue with the parameter `storeSession` is clearly a bug but I never expect that this will be still fixed in the official TYPO3 v10 as widgets are in general removed in TYPO3 v11 already.
Nevertheless I reported it and it can be found here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/98173